# continue statment not executing correctly within for loop+matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, continue

I have the following code:

```
for i=1:length(files)
    for j=1:length(files(i,1).day)
        if ((1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour)) ~=  24)
            continue
        end
        for h = 1:24
            if ((1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour(h).halfhour)) ~= 2)
                continue
            end

            if isempty(1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour))
                continue
            end
            dayPSD = [];
            for h2=1:2
                dayPSD = [dayPSD; files(i,1).day(j).hour(h).halfhour(h2).data{8}'];
            end
        end
    end
end
```

where

```
  files=1x3 structure
  files(i,1).day=1x335 structure that contains 1 field hour which is a 1x24 structure
  files(i,1).day.hour=1x24 structure that contains 1 field halfhour which is a 1x2 structure
```

I am trying to loop through i and j, but when 1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour) ~= 24 (so when the hours are less than 24) I would like to exit the loop and continue onto the next iteration of the for loop. I would also like it to exit the loop and continue onto the next iteration of the for loop if 1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour(h).halfhour) ~= 2 (so when the half hours are less than 2) or if 1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour is an empty cell (no data).

The current code I have written only seems to skip a loop index if 1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour ~=24.

What am I doing wrong? Also how do I get it to continue onto the next iteration if any of those conditions are met? I've been banging my head on this for a while, and I know I'm probably making a simple mistake, but if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific about which loop index you want to skip whenever you mention it? You have two nested loops; the `continue` in `if ((1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour)) ~=  24)` will skip one iteration of the `for j=1:length(files(i,1).day)` loop while the `continue` in `if ((1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour(h).halfhour)) ~= 2)` and the one in `if sempty(1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour))` will skip an iteration of the `for h = 1:24` loop.

Comment: I would like both of them to break out of the j loop index please

Comment: Then try replacing the `continue`s with  `break`s (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is:

```
for i=1:length(files)
    for j=1:length(files(i,1).day)
        if ((1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour)) ~=  24)
            continue
        end
        for h = 1:24
            if ((length(files(i,1).day(j).hour(h).halfhour)) ~= 2)
                break
            end

            if isempty(files(i,1).day(j).hour)
                break
            end
            dayPSD = [];
            for h2=1:2
                dayPSD = [dayPSD; files(i,1).day(j).hour(h).halfhour(h2).data{8}'];
            end
        end
    end
end
```

so when either condition is met, the flow of execution will exit the `for h=..` loop, and as there is no other statement in the `for j=1...` loop, the code will in effect skip that iteration.

Also note that `if ((1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour(h).halfhour)) ~= 2)` is comparing a vector `(1:length(..))` to a scalar `2` which results in a vector of booleans. The `if` part will only be executed if all its elements are `true` which is most likely never the case.

Comment: So this is working correctly for the first statement but it doesn't seem to be skipping the iterations for when 1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour(h).halfhour)) ~= 2) and when it's empty.This was this issue I was having, is it not abiding by the second conditions

Comment: Hum, your condition `1:length(files(i,1).day(j).hour(h).halfhour)) ~= 2` is probably never met as you are comparing a vector with a scalar, resulting in a vector of boolean. Is this what you want? See my updated answer.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the `if` statements (or prints) to see whether you actually ever get there.

Comment: You're exactly correct! I actually changed both conditions to       if length(files(i,1).day(j).hour ~=24 and if length(files(i,1).day(j).hour(h).halfhour) ~=2. Thanks so much! I thought it might be something little and needed the extra logic help of skipping to the next iterations out of the j loop from the h loop.